# Javascript - Appending for loop index to a variable inside loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target a list of elements using a for loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; ++i){
    console.log(i)
    target[i].classList.remove('redText')
    anchor[i].classList.remove('redText')
}
```

The expected result is:

```
target1.classList.remove('redText')
anchor1.classList.remove('redText')
target2.classList.remove('redText')
anchor2.classList.remove('redText')

....etc.
```

in the console I get

`ReferenceError: target is not defined`

Which means the index is not being appended to `target` and `anchor`.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: Is 'target1' an element id?

Comment: Makes sure `target` is referencing a collection of DOM elements or make sure `target` is declared in your code.

Comment: Not an expert here, but aren't you lacking the initialization of the target array?

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out. They are element ids... I'm using a templating engine on the back end so the way they are defined might be a little confusing for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; ++i){
    console.log(i)
    document.getElementById('target' + i).classList.remove('redText')
    document.getElementById('anchor' + i).classList.remove('redText')
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7keju/).

Comment: I'm assuming this would have worked in normal circumstances. But I realize now my question is misleading because my logic is linked to elements being generated by a back-end templating engine. I found a solution, but it's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: How does the way the HTML is generated affect things?

Comment: @AllTheTime your question was very specific and this is the right answer to the question you asked. Certainly should be selected as the answer.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet well what I meant was that your solution didn't work in my circumstances. The element id's being targeted were generated by a for loop within the template engine so `target1` `target2` etc. don't actually exist when the javascript loop run. But your answer is obviously useful and correct, so I will accept it. Sorry for the confusion.